# iOS: UIImagePickerController and ResignFirstResponder

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimagepickercontroller, resignfirstresponder

I have an application that allows the user to select a photo from their camera roll, and display it in a UIImageView. But, after they tap on which image they would like to display, the camera roll's view does not disappear. So, I figured that I would need to simply call `[sender resignFirstResponder];`. But, this did not do the trick. I've been trying multiple things and doing searching around, but to no avail. I'm very new to Objective-C, so any help is much appreciated. Here is the code I'm working with:
(imgPicker is the UIImagePickerController.)

```
 - (IBAction)grabImage(id)sender {
        self.imgPicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
        self.imgPicker.delegate = self;
        self.imgPicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

        if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
            _popover = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:imgPicker];
            [_popover presentPopoverFromRect:self.imageView.bounds inView:self.imageView permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
        } 

        else {
            [self presentModalViewController:imgPicker animated:YES];
        }
        [self.imgPicker resignFirstResponder];
    }
```

And this may or may not be relevant to the issue:

```
    - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)img editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editInfo {
        if (imageView.image == nil) {
            imageView.image = img;
            [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            return;

        }

        if (imageView2.image == nil) {
            imageView2.image = img;
            [[picker parentViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need just this line to dismiss modal picker in your delegate method:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

resignFirstResponder in this case is useless

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to dismiss only picker view and not parent view of picker

you just have to use:

```
[picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

and you are done.